# Inexistence of equivalent vectors in hyperbolic geometry.

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

A translation defined by vector $\vec{v}=\vec{AB}$, $\tau=\tau_{\vec{v}}$, is, by definition, the composite of the reflections $\rho_2 \circ \rho_1 $, where $\rho_1$ is the reflection in the perpendicular bissector of $AB$ and $\rho_2$ is the reflection in the perpendicular line to $AB$ through $B$.

In euclidean geometry I can find two equivalent vectors that will define the same translation, but that does'nt happen in hyperbolic geometry. I'm needing help on proving this: $\tau_{\vec{AB}}=\tau_{\vec{CD}} \iff \vec{AB}, \vec{CD}$ are collinear vectors with same orientation and magnitude.

Thanks.

Comment: That would break the new 5th postulate. Stating that from a point outside a line, there exist an infinity of parallel lines to the first that go through that point.

Comment: But hyperbolic geometry does break the 5th postulate; the substitute fot it is "there are at least two lines non-intersecting a given line through a point outside of it" (and consequently infinite lines)

Comment: Indeed. But colinearity of vectors would mean that there exist one and only one parallel going through that point. IMO the proof you want has to show that if there exist colinearity, then there is at most one parallel going through one point outside a line.

Comment: Problem is a bit that there is not an unique vector moving A to B there are many different vectors doing that I guess you need to define an unique translation on a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT

Every isometry (and translation is one of them) has the property that if $A'$ is the image of $A$ and  $B'$ is the image of $B$ then $d(AB) = d(A'B')$

But the question is what happens with $d(AA')$ and $d(BB')$ ?

In Euclidean geometry rotations do not have the property that the distance between a point and its image in the translation is the same.  so $ d(AA') \not= d(BB')$

In Euclidean geometry translations have the property that the distance between a point and its image in the translation is the same.  so $ d(AA') = d(BB')$

After some reflection and testing I realised this is also  **not** the case with hyperbolic translations.

The distance between a point and its image differs, they are the shortest along the line that contains the vector an the further away the larger the distance 
(the points form a Saccheri quadrilateral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccheri_quadrilateral )

From this alone you can prove your statement

Comment: Note that Möbius transforms preserve the hyperbolic distance.

Comment: yes but the question is which hyperbolic distance is preserved , only the "internal" distances of the object are preserved, not the distances between  object and image (compare with rotations) added bit to answer

Comment: The OP may also be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercycle_(geometry)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PROPOSITION 9.11 (GreenBerg 1993,p.331). it says:

If T is a translation along t and m is any line perpendicular to t, 
 then there is a unique line l perpendicular to t such that 
 T is the composeition of reflection of m and reflection of l.